# How to indicate the last indice in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, email, indices

I have a simple mail() script that sends to multiple emails dynamically by seperating the emails with commas.

```
<?php

$sendto = array("email@gmail.com", "email@zoho.com", "email@mail.usf.edu");
foreach ($sendto as $email)
{
    if ($email is the last indice in the array..) // <-- here
        $to = $email;
    else
        $to = $email . ', ';
}

$subject = "test message";
$msg = "this is a test";

if (mail($to, $subject, $msg)) 
    echo "message sent";
else 
    echo "uh oh";
?>
```

How do I identify if (this is the last piece of data in my array) ?

Comment: String concations in a loop. Kill me

Comment: @ColeJohnson I can help you with that - what is your current location ? :)

Comment: @Cole: There are two kinds of stupidity: 1. Not knowing; 2. Mocking those who don't know. The latter is far greater.

Comment: @alfasin Is Southern California good?

Comment: @ColeJohnson it's SF, and the answer is "hell yeah" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php includes `implode` or `join` which will work much better here:

```
$to = implode(', ', $sendto);
```

Answer (score 5):

No need.

```
$to = implode(', ', $sendto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your if clause use the [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function:

```
if ($email == end($sendto))
```

Comment: this answered my question directly and is appreciated, as are the others for the refactoring value

Comment: @khanahk: Except it doesn't. `array(1, 2, 4, 2);`